# How can I share a variable between multiple functions of a class in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want the page load to initialize "self.var" and then share this output with functions 'shared1' and "shared2"  within the "main" class.

I want to avoid declaring self.var each time I call "shared1" or "shared2".

I also do not want to use request.sessions because this requires additional overhead when serializing self.var

this is my views.py:

```
class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = ['test',"test2"]
        print('check var declaration')

    def pageload(self,request):
        context = {"nothing": "nothing"}
        return render(request, "index.html", context)

    def shared1(self):
        s1alt = ", ".join(self.var)
        context = {"var": s1alt}
        return JsonResponse(context)

    def shared2(self):
        s2 = ":".join(self.var)
        context = {"var": s2alt}
        return JsonResponse(context)
```

this is my urls.py:

```
path('home/',views.main().pageload,name="categories"),
path('ajaxgets1/',views.main.shared1,name="ajaxgets1"),
path('ajaxgets2/',views.main.shared2,name="ajaxgets2"),
```

Comment: You are assigning `None` to `s1alt` and `s2alt`; the `.append()` method doesn't return anything, its effect is purely in the modification of the list it's invoked on.

Comment: @jasonharper sorry that was intended to just be a generic manipulation. edited. thanks

Comment: Ok, it's not clear just what your question is.  In what way does this code fail, or otherwise not meet your needs?  Note that your `s1` and `s2` local variables are pointless, you might as well use `self.var` directly in the places where you're using those variables.

Comment: @jasonharper see edits. this will yield the desired result but executes def __init__() twice, but I only want it executed once with same functonality.

Comment: If you want the values to be shared between page loads, you shouldn't be creating multiple instances of `main()`.

Comment: How should I accomplish that? If I use the above edited urls.py I can't access the self object in the functions